# AWS Lambda invoke exception "No LambdaFunction annotation for method invoke"

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, exception, aws-lambda, aws-java-sdk

I am invoking a Lambda function from my Java code that is running inside Spark process.

The invocation is failing with following exception:

> 23:22:50,043 ERROR com.gravty.batch.process.BitProcessImpl -
>   com.amazonaws.services.lambda.invoke.LambdaSerializationException: No
>   LambdaFunction annotation for method invoke

Does anyone has any idea about this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved it by using interface with @LambdaFunction annotation.

my lambda interface:

```
public interface MyLambdaService {
    @LambdaFunction
    ApiGatewayProxyResponse execute(ApiGatewayRequest bit);
}
```

this is how I created the lambda client:

```
MyLambdaService lambdaService = LambdaInvokerFactory.builder().lambdaClient(AWSLambdaClientBuilder.defaultClient())
                    .lambdaFunctionNameResolver((method, annotation, config) -> "ENV_SPECIFIC_FUNCTION_NAME").build(MyLambdaService.class);
```